# How to align image content on stackpanel in metro app

Tags: winrt-xaml, stackpanel

I've got a Stackpanel which is set to horizontal orientation and Horizontal alighment is set to Stretch. Inside it I've got two elements: 1. TextBlocks 2. Image. I want the 2nd one to display on extreme right.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <TextBlock>Hello World</TextBlock>
    <Image Height="100" Width="100" />
</StackPanel>
```

How do I accomplish it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it.

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock>Hello World</TextBlock>
    <Image Height="100" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
</Grid>
```

Just don't use a `StackPanel`.

// Best of luck!